# Revoke 'Store files' permission

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, file-storage, cordova-plugin-file

My issue is linked to Chrome Browser. I'm developing an app using Сordova and https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.

This plugin is asking a permission to use persistent storage on the end-user browser such as:

[image]

I have clicked "ALLOW" a long time ago and this popup does not show anymore.

Right now, I'd like to prevent my user to have that popup and therefore  I need to revoke that permission within my computer to perform some tests.

I have tried various tests to change browser settingб but I do not succeed on revoking that permission. I'm not speaking about location / flash or other permission, but that specific storage permission.

If anyone has a clue on how to revoke that one, I'll be glad to test it and provide my feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Go to chrome://settings/siteData, search for localhost and there you'll be able to clear File system storage.

[image: chrome screenshot]

Comment: That's what this does. It also deletes the files obiviously, as having no permission but the files wouldn't make sense.

Comment: By removing the corresponding site in the cookies list, it does what is needed here. BTW, the structure of cookies has been modified in the latest chrome.

Comment: I've updated the URL and screenshot to reflect the latest Chrome version (at the time of writing v69).